# How to create a folder in a directory where user need admin permission

Tags: java

Hi I need to put some files in some directory which myself as a user have no rights but for administrator has rights. In this case I want my program should ask for admin username and password. If i put correct admin username and password then i must be able to put the folder in that directory. Otherwise i should get a message box for wrong username and password

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible in java. without the permission of root/admin the user cannot craete any folder or directory in root file system. The folder needs admin access.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cant do this with Java alone, you may need [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/).

Comment: Does she need to do this via Java or is it mis-tagged? It seems like she could do this through `chmod` et al., but the `Java` tag seems to be misleading.

Comment: JNI is Java Native Interface, which is the only option to change permissions etc' from Java

Comment: I wan to do the same thing using java

Comment: Down because this is unspecific

Answer (score 1):

At least in Unix-like operating systems (e.g. Linux), you cannot possibly do that in Java, not even with JNI. You need a binary executable file (not a shell script, java program etc.), owned by root, with the set-user-ID-on-execution bit set. This program should (but technically, doesn't have to) check that you are permitted to do what you want to do (by asking you for the password or whatever) and do the operation for you. BTW, `su` and `sudo` are like this.

The other possibility, and I think that's the standard way in Windows, is to have a daemon program running (started by the admin so it has the necessary privileges) and this daemon waits for commands to process (by some means of IPC, network etc.), checks if the user should be allowed to do that (however this is determined) and eventually processes those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder such that the permissions are as follows: (but you get a choice!)

Choose this option if you (and the 'others') want to be able to save, copy, or move files into this folder, but not see the contents of it:

```
 ___________________________________
|        | User   | R | W | X | Val |
|--------+--------+---+---+---+-----|
| user   | you    | X | √ | X |  2  |
| group  | admins | √ | √ | √ |  7  |
| others | N/A    | X | √ | X |  2  |
|________|________|___|___|___|_____|
```

Choose this option if you (and the 'others') should not have any privileges to this folder:

```
 ___________________________________
|        | User   | R | W | X | Val |
|--------+--------+---+---+---+-----|
| user   | you    | X | X | X |  0  |
| group  | admins | √ | √ | √ |  7  |
| others | N/A    | X | X | X |  0  |
|________|________|___|___|___|_____|
```

Does this solve your problem or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Both tables are same buddy. :)

Comment: Whoops, I copied and pasted it, but forgot to change the second one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.6 the [java.io.File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable%28boolean%29) has the following methods:

1. [setReadable()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean%29)
2. [setWritable()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean%29)
3. [setExecutable()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable%28boolean%29)

Do a guess what they do. There's a overloaded method with a `boolean ownerOnly`. This should be the solution if you're already logged in as admin (even more; in Windows it's impossible to give a file admin-only rights if you're already not the admin).